# EXTJS getting the right call

Tags: ajax, web-services, rest, extjs, extjs4

I am making a combobox in EXTJS which should be populated by a REST service. Like this example: 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/form/forum-search.html

I want to make a call like this:

```
https://smartadresse.dk/service/locations/3/detect/json/granskoven%20glostrup?apikey=1E718C7E-70D7-4E3A-AB40-AF6671FDCB57
```

But it makes it like this:

```
https://smartadresse.dk/service/locations/3/detect/json/?apikey=1E718C7E-70D7-4E3A-AB40-AF6671FDCB57&query=granskoven%20glostrup
```

How do you tell extjs to change that? My Ext proxy looks like this:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'jsonp',
    url : 'https://smartadresse.dk/service/locations/3/detect/json/',
    extraParams: {
        apikey: '1E718C7E-70D7-4E3A-AB40-AF6671FDCB57',
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'streetName'
    },
```

Comment: Have you tried putting it at the end directly `url : https://smartadresse.dk/service/locations/3/detect/json/granskoven%20glostrup`

Comment: It works fine entering "granskoven%20glostrup". The problem is that "granskoven%20glostrup" is the search word being sent to the external server.

Answer (score 0):

I have also noticed that you aren't actually using the `type: 'rest'` in your proxy, but the jsonp one as `type: 'jsonp'`.  Do you need to be going to a different domain with your call?  If not, you should change the type to rest to see if it is implemented in the way you expect.

JSONP has actually nothing to do with the REST protocol, it is for going to different domains than were your page is hosted.  JSONP works like a regular ajax call in that all the actions and parameters are sent as post data or on the url by your configuration.  From the documentation though, it appears that you could get what you want by using the `api` configuration option which has methods for CRUD which should be very similar.

Comment: I am going to a different domain. Tried using the api parameter. However not really sure what code i should write. What goes into 
api : {
create : '*',
read : '*',
update : '*',
destroy : '*'
},

Comment: looks like you are trying to do a read, so api: {
    create  : undefined,
    read    : "granskoven%20glostrup",
    update  : undefined,
    destroy : undefined
} may work.

Comment: not sure if you're api does the other actions, but you would have to define them if so.

Comment: It does format it correctly if I make it like this:
read   : "https://smartadresse.dk/service/locations/3/detect/json/granskoven%20glostrup", however it still sends on the "query" parameter.

Comment: well, you're doing something that looks like it's out of scope of what Extjs designed.  Do you need to remove the query parameter?  If so, I can show you how, but the extra effort of doing so may not be worth it if it's not completely necessary.